# Git GUI like HG Workbench in MS Windows

Tags: git, user-interface, mercurial

I am looking for a good Git GUI which looks and works like [HG Workbench](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/quick.html).

Is there anything interesting? Preferably freeware.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default Git Gui that comes with [Msysgit](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) looks quite like that.

Comment: It does look quite like it, but is not exactly it. If someone used Hg Workbench before and comes to Git Gui he is bound to get confused and irritated...

Answer (score 34):

My favorite graphical git-client is [SourceTree](http://sourcetreeapp.com/) (available for Windows and Mac). SourceTree can manage git and Hg (Mercurial) repositorys.

By the way: SourceTree supports git-flow, is **free for personal and commercial use** and is made by Atlassian, the company behind BitBucket, Stash JIRA and other known products.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: SourceTree is also my favorite git client for Windows. Im using it since the beta!

Comment: FYI, it only runs on Windows 7+

Comment: SourceTree is not exactly free. The EULA says it grants a free 30 day evaluation period, after that you're suppose to get a license to continue to use it. The app might work just fine after those 30 days, but it can land you in hot water if you use it commercially. Now it seems you can get the license for "free", but first you need to sign a lengthy customer agreement that could contain just about anything (go read that 14 pages of legal babble). If a company makes legally using their "free" app this confusing, it certainly doesn't make me trust them.

Comment: SourceTree **is** exactly free. The circumstance that you have to register after 30 days does not change that. Anyway, if you installed their software, you already accepted their EULA. In fact, its not unusal for Atlassian that you have to register their free software, I think they just want to track how many people and companies use it. I dont even think this makes Atlassian less trustworthy. Their products are used by thousands of companies and hunderts of thousands of people.

Comment: @fnkr I'm no lawyer, so I used some online tool to analyze their registration license (which is a separate thing from the EULA). It didn't find anything fishy, so at the end of the day I ended up using SourceTree. It doesn't have all the features (or maybe I just haven't found them yet) that the Workbench has, but it is the next best thing.

Comment: Very neat and easy to use tool.

Comment: ..and is slow as molasses...tortoiseHg workbench is so much nicer

Comment: From some version onwards you need BitBucket account to use SourceTree.

Answer (score 3):

How about git gui, Tortoise Git, SmartGit, Git extensions?

Comment: [TortoiseGit has no workbench](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=929).

Comment: Yeah, I liked TortoiseHg and have been disappointed so far with TortoiseGit.

Comment: I use `TortoiseGit` > `Show Log`, pretty simple but does the job if you're familiar with TortoiseHg.  I'd also like something more like `Workbench` though, SourceTree quite a different experience IMO.